# Проблема с парсингом xml на linux

Tags: java, linux, xml, spring, кодировка

Мне необходимо распарсить xml, который содержит русские буквы. Он лежит в postgresql базе. На windows проблем с этим не возникло,  использую

```
 doc.getElementsByTagNameNS ("*","название_тега");
```

Но когда запускаю ту же программу на linux, элементы не находятся.

Приложение написано на Spring (App extends SpringBootServletInitializer) и запущено под tomcat(нужна именно конфигурация war).

Ниже приведен код считывания xml. Есть подозрение что проблема с кодировкой, но как ее решить не знаю. Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
 public Document readXml(String xml) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    Document document = db.parse(is);
    return document;

}
```

UPD:

Сейчас проверила как он пишет в файл - кодировка KOI8-R. То есть в поле названия тега записывается не UTF-8, а KOI8-R, и поэтому не может найти подходящий тэг.

Comment: Приведите пжста код, который получает значение для параметра `xml` который Вы передаете в метод `readXml(String xml)`

Comment: Видимо и название самой кодировки испорчено. Насколько я знаю, не существует кодировки с таким именем, поддерживающей кириллицу.

Comment: @Sergi п║п╡п╣п╢п═п╣пЁп║п╪п╣я─я┌ вот такой текст получает функция getElementsByTagNameNS, а функция readXml получает xml : с тегами вида <ns2:СведРегСмерт ДатаЗапис="" НомерЗапис=""> и так далее, файл большой

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой костыль с перекодировкой русских слов решил вопрос, но я уверена есть нормальное решение.
Пусть пока полежит здесь

```
public static String magic(String str) {
        byte ptext[] = new byte[0];
        try {
            ptext = str.getBytes("KOI8_R");
            String value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
            return value;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }
```